# How to $.post a js variable and store it to php for later use,similarly to LocalStorage?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, mysql

In local storage,we store for example `localStorage.setItem("test",$('#testinput').val());`

And 2 years later,as long we have'nt cleared our browser's local storage we just ask for the key in LS and we get it back like this `$('#testinput').val(localStorage.getItem("test"));`

Now let's say (because LS is available only within one system and one browser) I want to store this particular data to a server-side PHP file, and have it available there to be accessed whenever I want, what would be the simplest and most common practice to do that based on my example and my snippet below*?
Should I store it in a PHP cookie?

Note that I have some familiarity with $.post and $.get with jquery, and concerning PHP I know as much as getting the request and send a response back, I just started learning.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        function storeVALUE() {
            localStorage.setItem("test", $('#testinput').val());
        }

        function retrieveVALUE() {
            $('#testinput').val(localStorage.getItem("test"));
        }

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <button onclick="storeVALUE()">STORE VALUE</button><button onclick="retrieveVALUE()">RETRIEVE VALUE</button>
    <input id="testinput">
</body>

</html>
```

*SO snippets do not access LS, but you get the idea

Comment: Do you want this data stored on the server or on the client?  If on the server then it sounds like what you're looking for is to start using a database.

Comment: So you need to have a session for a user and store data into the database and retrieve it. It is a bit too broad to show all the stuff to do that. Plenty of tutorials out there.

Comment: @david in the server

Comment: @VaggelisNos: Then you're basically asking how to use a database with PHP.  Given that terminology you should be able to find many tutorials and examples to get you started.  I imagine the recommended approach would be to use MySQL as the database (most common) and PDO as the PHP library to access that database (most modern).

Comment: @epascarello do you have any handy ?

Answer (score 0):

if this is necessary with your code , you can store variable value using cookies in json format and later use it using `$_COOKIE[$cookie_name]`